# Limit reducer output file size with Scalding

Tags: hadoop, cascading, scalding

I'm using Scalding, and we have approximately 5.5GB output file sizes. (eg. for 30 reducers, there's 30 5.5GB files). Is there a way to say, limit output files to be 512MB each? I could increase the number of reducers, but was hoping something a bit more dynamic.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to limit file size in the reducer so the number of reducers seems to be the way to go. Could you explain a bit more why you need to limit the file size?

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure about Scalding, but in typical map reduce you can increase number of output files by implementing multiple output formats. You can generate file name prefixes based up on keys (by default it uses part as prefix).

Comment: @BenWatson I think what Durga meant was, you can make custom output file format that would slice the output into multiple files which is a reasonable suggestion given that the requestor doesn't want to change the number of reducers.